# Use Oracle Wallet without installing the Oracle Client

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am using OCI lib to connect a client application to Oracle database. I would like to use Wallet to store the keys but it looks like the only way to store the key in Wallet is by using mkstore or orapki. 
Those tools are available when installing Oracle Client but I don't want my customers to download Oracle Client on their machine.

Is there any way that I can create and store the credentials in a Wallet without installing Oracle Client? Can I redistribute orapki or mkstore? Is there any API?

Comment: If you're building a client/ server application, you'll need to have an Oracle client install on every machine to use OCI.  Perhaps you mean that you want to deploy your application with the Oracle Instant Client so you want to avoid doing a full Oracle client install?

Comment: if my customers don't use SSL connection, I can send them OCI library (redistribute it with my code) and they don't need to install Oracle Client. But if they want to use SSL connection, they need to store server certificate in Wallet, to do that they need orapki or mkstore utilities. Both these tools are part of Oracle Client. So I am looking for a solution to not use orapki or mkstore but a way to problematically store server certificate in a wallet file.

Comment: I'm still confused.  Are you redistributing the Oracle Instant Client now?  And you want to avoid doing a full Oracle client install?

Comment: This is what my customer does today: 1- get server certificate 2- install Oracle Client 3-use mkstore/orapki (part of Oracle client) to create a wallet and store sever certificate in that wallet. 4- pass the location of the wallet to my application. But I want to eliminate the steps 2 and 3. I need a way to programmatically create the wallet and store the server certificate.